# How can I organise the Bag in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Is there a way to organise the items within each of the sections of the bag in Pokemon X and Y?

Examples:

- Order TMs Alphabetically
- Order TMs by Number
- Order Pokeballs by Sell
  Price/Quality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the button with the two circular arrows (see the bottom boxed button) to sort TMs (in the TM compartment of your bag) alphabetically or by number.

[image]

For Poke Balls, you don't have a specific compartment for them (unlike some previous generation games), but you can sort the items by type, name and amount (either most to least, or least to most).

Comment: Does this ordering have any affect on the In Battle item menu?

Comment: @JamieP Yes it does. The battle item menu will be sorted according to how the items are sorted in your bag.

Comment: I just wanna know if there is a way to avoid having to scroll across in battle to get to my Pokeballs every time I wanna catch something.

Comment: @JamieP Well, you will usually have to scroll across the multiple pages if you have more than 6 different types of Poke Balls. If you're throwing more than one, you can instead make use of the 'Last item used' button in the item menu (that is, if you didn't use any other item). Or you could buy a lot of the Poke Balls you usually use and sort by 'From Most' in the bag menu.

Comment: If you sort items by type, the standard 'Pokeball' will be the first ball type in the battle menu

Comment: Jerry, Dr. You guys need a big high five for helping me out. ;)

Answer (score 3):

When you go into the items menu try pressing the buttons at the bottom of the touch screen.

Comment: Hey Phil, welcome to Arqade! While your answer may be technically correct (The feature Jamie is looking for *is* one of those buttons), it is not really that helpful without a little more clarity. If I were to direct you towards perhaps reading up on a brief "How do I write a good answer?" guide, which would be more helpful; "Click on one of the links at the top of the site." or "[Here's a link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to a helpful guide that may tell you how to improve your answers to earn reputation."?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I shall take a look.
Unfortunately I was unable to gather the specifics required for a detailed reply (such as an image and options available) at the time.
I figured a poor answer was better than no answer, especially considering a detailed answer would follow shortly after. 
This earlier post _might_ have been enough to see Jamie through his problem sooner.
In the worst case, I planned to edit my post once I arrived home.
Perhaps I should not have posted at all.

Comment: Not at all Phil, I honestly thought your answer was fine, esp. as (at the time) a person with less than 10 reputation, you wouldn't have been able to inline pictures anyway. Even still, you recieved 2 upvotes and no downvotes, so people obviously thought your answer was helpful. We generally point new posters to the [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and How to ask/answer pages, its habitual, but I'm sure @TrentHawkins just meant to help, not to put you off posting entirely :)